# ajax doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I miss?

1.php:

```
<button id = "testtext">Show</button>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

js.js:

```
$("#testtext").bind("click", previewNewShortnameFunc);
function previewNewShortnameFunc() {
    var lalalatext = "lalala";
    var lalalaint = 100;
    console.log("sent: " + lalalatext + " and " + lalalaint);
    $.ajax ({
        url: "testprint4.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : {str: lalalatext, int: lalalaint},
        success: function(data) {
            window.open("testprint4.php");
        }
    });
}
```

testprint4.php

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['str'];
$int = $_POST['int'];
echo $str;
echo $int;
?>
```

I see blank page instead of lalala100. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you are redirecting the script to the submit page than why are you using ajax?

Comment: you just send some information by post in ajax (which doing the job well but you don't display it) and then when it's done you ask to open a window but you don't send any informations inside

Comment: did you check console in browser?

Comment: @Moiz just testing if data transported correctly.

Comment: IN ajax there is no need of opening window just show the responce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code includes two separate HTTP requests. You are first doing an Ajax request getting that response prior to redirecting user to request same script w/o any parameter, thus resulting in empty page.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "testprint4.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : {str: lalalatext, int: lalalaint},
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

This part makes browser requesting the script with provided data as POST. *When the response has been received* it is available in `data` of callback linked with `success`-property. The request is finished then.

Instead of processing that response with your expected content you use

```
window.open("testprint4.php");
```

to open new window of browser for requesting same script again, this time using GET request w/o any argument. Therefore you will see a blank page.

Comment: Ohhhh...Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. jQuery Ajax make this call asynchronously, so, window.open will request testprint4.php without data passed in ajax call. To see the desired resulto, replace `window.open('testprin4.php')` to `console.log(data)`.